# BASH better way to monitor files

Tags: bash, logging, monitoring

I've made a Bash script to monitor some server log files for certain data and my method probably isn't the most efficient.

One section specifically bugs me is that I have to write a newline to the monitored log so that the same line wont be read over continually.

Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

serverlog=/home/skay/NewWorld/server.log
onlinefile=/home/skay/website/log/online.log
offlinefile=/home/skay/website/log/offline.log
index=0

# Creating the file
if [ ! -f "$onlinefile" ]; then
    touch $onlinefile
    echo "Name                  Date            Time" >> "$onlinefile"
fi
if [ ! -f "$offlinefile" ]; then
    touch $offlinefile
    echo "Name                  Date            Time" >> "$offlinefile"
fi

# Functions
function readfile {

# Login Variables
loginplayer=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $4}'`
logintime=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $2}'`
logindate=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game" | awk '{print $1}'`

# Logout Variables
logoutplayer=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $4}'`
logouttime=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $2}'`
logoutdate=`tail -1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game" | awk '{print $1}'`

# Check for Player Login
    if [ ! -z "$loginplayer" ]; then
        echo "$loginplayer          $logindate  $logintime" >> "$onlinefile"
        echo "Player $loginplayer login detected" >> "$serverlog"
        line=`grep -rne "$loginplayer" $offlinefile | cut -d':' -f1`
        if [ "$line" > 1 ]; then
            sed -i "$line"d $offlinefile
            unset loginplayer
                    unset line
        fi
    fi
# Check for Player Logout
    if [ ! -z "$logoutplayer" ]; then
        echo "$logoutplayer         $logoutdate $logouttime" >> "$offlinefile"
        echo "Player $loginplayer logout detected" >> "$serverlog"
        line=`grep -rne "$logoutplayer" $onlinefile | cut -d':' -f1`
        if [ "$line" > 1 ]; then
            sed -i "$line"d $onlinefile
            unset logoutplayer
            unset line
        fi
    fi
}

# Loop
while [ $index -lt 100 ]; do
    readfile
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want people to review your code, codereview.stackexchange.com is a better forum

Answer (score 0):

instead of using multiple

```
tail -n 1 file
```

try the following construct:

```
tail -f file | while read line;do
   echo "read: $line"
done
```

it will be much more reliable...and won't read the same line twice ;)

note: by using new processes of grep/awk/etc you are burning away processes...it's not that it is critical, but usually process creation is expensive...but if new lines occur rarely it's perfectly fine

where i want'ed to get is: if you are intrested, take a look at bash builting string manipulator function replace $(x/aa} ${x//aa} and friends..or try to use extended regexpes with grep